# Are "there is" and "there are" with a compound subject, both correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, compound-subjects

Good pm, I would like to be further clarified if the following sentences are correct or incorrect, but I believe both are correct.

> There **is** a cat and a dog.
>   There **are** a dog and a cat.

My point is, are these sentences correct? *Yes* or *no*? And why?

Comment: I am more interested in your expression: *Good "pm"* do you mean "afternoon"?

Comment: Yes..would you pls share any explanation to this matter if both sentences are correct.

Comment: Please provide some research you have done to answer the question specifically. Also, questions asking for grammatical validation without any specific concerns are not for ELU.

Comment: Related:[Mixing plural and singular list items with a single verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59808/mixing-plural-and-singular-list-items-with-a-single-verb) and [There is/are for multiple subjects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114570/there-is-are-for-multiple-subjects) and [Is “there're” (similar to “there's”) a correct contraction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-therere-similar-to-theres-a-correct-contraction) This last one has the answer you're looking for.

Comment: All I want to know is is these sentences are correct and why: 'There is a cat and a dog' and ';There are a cat and a dog''. Thanks!

Comment: Please, read the answers in the linked questions. If you are still confused, edit your question show the research and explain why you are not happy with the answers supplied. You want a yes or a no answer? OK, here it is "yes" and "no". It depends. Do the research.

Comment: There is a dog and a cat. (ellipsis) of There is a dog and there is a cat.




The first one is an ellipisis of "there is a dog and there is a cat." We just omit the extra words.

Comment: There are a dog and a cat. (the verb number agrees with the verb number)

Comment: So, are these both sentences correct?

Comment: It depends how they are to be considered.

*There is a cat over here and a dog over there* is one thing.

*There are a cat and a dog over here/there/anywhere* is quite another.